# Wordpress: show comments on separate page

Tags: comments, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to show comments on separate page, on the page itself, so there will be only link to the comment page like www.example.com/my-post/comments (and great would be also to have /my-post/comments/name-of-some-comment for every single comment).

any idea, how can i do it? E.g. some plugin? I have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any plugin. basically you just need to copy either post or page template, which already has both post/page body and comments and then remove everything but the comments.

Check wordpress codex:

- [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags)
- [Custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates)
- [Query-based Template Files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Query-based_Template_Files)
- [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Most likely you will need to create your own conditional tag, or just check for particular query string (GET) parameter and apply your custom template